# AWS elastic beanstalk HTTP 502 when attempting to use load balancer to enable SSL/HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to preface this by stating that networking is not my forte but I have to work with it for my use case.

I'm attempting to get an HTTPS connection to my web app which runs on Apache Tomcat. I launched the container in AWS elastic beanstalk, and it worked completely fine when I was just using a single instance. It also worked fine when I put the load balancer in, leaving the default port listener and process as-is. However, as soon as I tried to redirect incoming connections to HTTPS, I get 502 errors. I checked in the console, and it's looking like there is no listener running on either port 443 or 8443 (the latter of which I have confirmed to be enabled in the server.xml file under tomcat's configuration folder), and when I check the Catalina log I note that the only protocol handler that appears to be running is the one set for port 8080 despite the config file clearly indicating otherwise. There are no errors in the log, which indicates that my app is launching correctly. In addition, the 502 bad gateway error page shows no other information -- no nginx version to indicate that the error is with the proxy, and no useful information in any of Amazon's logging.

I am completely stumped, since there is no real indication on Amazon's documentation that any further special configuration of their tomcat environment should be required to use HTTPS -- the extent of that is meant to occur in the EBS setup configuration where the load balancer and such are configured. Is it possible that you can't reconfigure an environment to use HTTPS retroactively and that I have to rebuild the entire environment to allow for this? I just feel like I'm banging my head against a wall for the past day and a half.

I have tried rebooting the instances, modifying the load balancer redirection configs, and switching the proxy server from nginx to apache httpd. Obviously, I expect the app to load rather than having this obnoxious refusal to cooperate continue (AWS has been like a raging bull that I've had the displeasure of having to wrangle for the past couple of weeks). Based on the logs, it looks like tomcat is trying to interpret the requests as unencrypted HTTP requests, so clearly something is missing...help!

Comment: Are you attempting to enable HTTPS for requests coming in to the load balancer (with plain HTTP between load balancer and ec2 instances), or are you attempting to enable HTTPS throughout?

Comment: I'm trying to enable HTTPS throughout the whole thing.

Comment: I'm going to try using the manual configuration files with another, self-signed certificate as a backend encryption and configure the load balancer to do decrypt and re-encrypt. Apparently you can get more nitty-gritty with the instance configuration if you upload a bundle of yaml files alongside your webapp...hopefully I can get this working...

Comment: Update: I have been working with the load balancer and instance configurations for the past day or so to no avail. The access logs are not displaying any incoming connections, despite the security groups and vpc being set up to allow the instances and load balancer to communicate. The 502 appears to be a result of failing health checks, but as far as I can tell the app is still running and the health check should succeed if the load balancer were actually connecting to the instance.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the health check, which needed a change to the port configuration in order for the instances not to be terminated after a time - maybe helps

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who experiences this headache in the future, here's what I did that (eventually) worked.

Buried pretty deep in AWS documentation is information about manual configuration of beanstalk environments using YAML and/or JSON files (from what I am aware, you can mix the syntax within the files). The .ebextensions folder has those files, and then the .platform folder has config specific to your server (in this case, it's Apache). I also got a self-signed certificate for end-to-end encryption, since the browser only sees the certificate that the load balancer is using and doesn't worry about the fact that the backend is self-signed. (I had to do a lot of reading up on SSL and security for this and it's going to be obsolete in a few years...le sigh)

You'll need two folders in your app's root directory (that is, if you unzip the WAR, the folders will be at the same level as the WEB-INF folder, if you're using Java EE or Spring).
Under .ebextensions, you will have to configure the load balancer (I also took the opportunity to specify my environment variables in this folder).

The config should look something like this (you can split up the files, as long as you name them something relatively easy to remember):

```
packages:
    yum:
       mod_ssl : []
Resources:
    AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
        Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
        Metadata:
            AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
                S3Auth:
                    type: "S3"
                    buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-705738864590"]
                    roleName:
                        "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
                            Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
                            OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
                            DefaultValue: (your instance profile name)
option_settings:
    aws:elbv2:listener:443:
        Protocol: HTTPS
        SSLCertificateArns: (put the ARN for your certificate here)
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
        Port: '443'
        Protocol: HTTPS
        StickinessEnabled: 'true'
        StickinessLBCookieDuration: '43200'
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
        ProxyServer: apache
files:
/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(paste your self-signed certificate's public key here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: (link your certificate's private key from the S3 bucket here)
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_start_httpd.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo service httpd restart
```

Then you need to have a configuration file to put the listeners up on ports 443 and 80 -- this goes under .platform (this is very much not obvious from the documentation and took me a not-insignificant amount of digging to find out -- if you try to put these under .ebextensions it will not work). It turns out a good deal of the trouble I was having was because the health checks were failing due to the port redirect I had -- I needed to put a rewrite condition for the redirect rule so that it wouldn't mess up the health checks.

.platform/httpd/conf.d/redirect.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
<If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</If>
```

.platform/httpd/conf.d/https.conf:

```
Listen 443
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ServerName            (your domain)
  SSLEngine             on
  SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
  SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
  SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder   On

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the certificate and key file names just have to match what you put in the file system configuration under .ebextensions.

Anyway, suffice to say that AWS spared nothing in making this a metric ton of seemingly-unnecessary work for me, and that I have even more reason to despise Jeff Bezos now.